# Asp.net MVC modal pop-up close after confirmation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem, when I confirm something in my Modal Pop Up I want it to close but it keeps showing in my screen.

This is my Code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#ModalDeleteButton').on("click", function(e) {
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    $.post("/Student/Delete/", {
        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
        id: id
      },
      function(data) {
        $('#myModal .close').click();
        var baseurl = '@Url.Action("Index")';

        var url = baseurl + "?message=" + data;
        window.location.href = url;

      });
  });
});
```

This is the button that I have to delete a register when the model is poped.up:

```
$('#ModalDeleteButton')
```

This is the button to close the pop-up:

```
$('#myModal .close')
```

When I click in the ModelDeleteButton I want the Modal Pop Up to close but I can't manage to do it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code

```
$('#closemodal').click(function() {
$('#modalwindow').modal('hide');
});
```

Or use can use HTML

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to close the modal programmatically using by calling the [`modal` method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) and passing `hide` as the argument.

```
$(function () {

    $(document).on("click", "#ModalDeleteButton", function (e) {

        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
        var data= { __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                    id: id
                  };
        $.post('@Url.Action("Delete","Student")',data).done(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            // do other things as needed
        });
    });

});
```

Assuming `myModal` is the `Id` of your modal div.